# Parse string value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an attribute of a list object in html like this:

```
<ul>
<li id="myID" add-param="{"type1":"myType1","type2":"myType2"}">Test</li>
</ul>
```

Having the list item with specified ID, how could I get the value myType1,myType2 by the key type, type2 ?

Thanks.

Comment: add-param="{"type1":"myType1","type2":"myType2"}" won't work, try : add-param="{'type1':'myType1','type2':'myType2'}"

Comment: add-param="{"type1":"myType1","type2":"myType2"}" is working in Firefox 4.0.1 and in IE 7 also. And the answer by Dogbert is compatibly working with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var json = JSON.parse($('#myID').attr('add-param'));

alert(json.type1) # myType1
```

Some old browsers don't have JSON.parse, you'll need to use this - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Sidenote: You should be using data attributes instead of defining your own custom attributes - http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Please note that not all browsers support the `JSON` object.

Comment: I have included the json2.js file in my page. And this is working with IE 7 and FF 4.0.1. Is there any other browser that doesn't support this, or is this supported by all browsers?